# How to modify javascript function in main js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing problem in javascript function. 
I have already define a function in almost 20 files and i can't modify them individually. Function is something like.

```
function next_question(thiss){
    //some code
}
```

I have already include a js file in all files and now want to did some task at the start of this function and also at end but can't edit this function in files. 
I can add code is separate JS file. i want above function as

```
function next_question(thiss){
   //## add disabled class here 

   //some code

   //## remove disabled class here 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override a javascript function, you can store the original in a variable, reset the `next_question` function and call the original within.

```
//oringal function
function next_question(thiss){
    console.log(thiss);
}

//override function
var original_next_question = next_question;
next_question = function(thiss){
    console.log('add disable');
    original_next_question.call(this, thiss);
    console.log('remove disable');
}

// calling now shows 3 console logs
next_question('some code');
```

using the `call` method calls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided individually.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vwsb12zd/3/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to do this however in javascript a function is like any other object and can be written over. The code below will work to REdefine the function only and will throw fatal errors if it executes prior to the declaration of the original function.

```js
next_question = function(this) {
       //## add disabled class here 

   //some code

   //## remove disabled class here 
}
```

Comment: Please provide details. What errors is your console giving?

Comment: i have differents pages site.com/questions1 and site.com/questions2 and answers of questions are submited by ajax. ajax code is placed in function which calls on onclick event of button. now i want to modify that function in which ajax code is placed.

Comment: Alright and why can't you edit this function in the .js file? all of these pages should be dirrected to the same JS file and edditing the function would be easy that way. However the answer i gave above should still work as long as it is executed after the initial function declaration. Please provide copy of your code and your console debug errors for any additional assistance!

Comment: function is placed in files not in JS File. but JS File is added in all files. so i can write code for all pages in JS File but can't edit these individually in files

Comment: This is verry bad practice. This function should have been placed in a .js file if the function is used on multiple pages. However my solution above will work if the .js file is called on each page after the inline script in which this function is declared. Now once again before i can be of ANY more help you MUST post your code and debug information. Thanks